# How to translate a string that contains a WordPress sitename

Tags: themes, translation, localization

currently I have this code:

```
<?php _e( 'Follow ' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . ' on Facebook', 'yanse' ); ?>
```

But I just get **Follow** to translate and it echoes "**Seguir** 'Site name' on Facebook"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sprintf`:

```
echo sprintf( __('Follow %s on Facebook', 'yanse'), get_bloginfo('name') );
```

Comment: Thanks, I know. What I want to translate is the following text "on Facebook"

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope it work for you!